# Creating a category tree table from an array of categories in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, tree, hierarchical-data

How to generate ids and parent_ids from the arrays of categories. The number or depth of subcategories can be anything between 1-10 levels.

Example PostgreSQL column. Datatype character varying array.

```
data_column
character varying[]             |               
----------------------------------
[root_1, child_1, childchild_1] |
[root_1, child_1, childchild_2] | 
[root_2, child_2]               |
```

I would like to convert the column of arrays into the table as shown below that I assume is called the Adjacency List Model. I know there is also the Nested Tree Sets Model and Materialised Path model.

Final output table

```
id | title        | parent_id
------------------------------
1  | root_1       | null
2  | root_2       | null  
3  | child_1      | 1
4  | child_2      | 2 
5  | childchild_1 | 3  
6  | childchild_2 | 3
```

Final output tree hierarchy

```
root_1
--child_1
----childchild_1
----childchild_2
root_2
--child_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=def27807bb7e38625633a57384e39c85)

You can do this with a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS 
(  SELECT data[1] as title, 2 as idx, null as parent, data FROM t   -- 1

   UNION

   SELECT data[idx], idx + 1, title, data                           -- 2
   FROM cte
   WHERE idx <= cardinality(data)
)
SELECT DISTINCT                                                     -- 3 
    title,
    parent
FROM cte
```

1. The starting query of the recursion: Get all root elements and data you'll need within the recursion
2. The recursive part: Get element of new index and increase the index
3. After recursion: Query the columns you finally need. The `DISTINCT` removes tied elements (e.g. two times the same `root_1`).

Now you have created the hierarchy. Now you need the ids.
You can generate them in many different ways, for example using the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (...)
SELECT 
    *,
    row_number() OVER ()
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        title,
        parent
    FROM cte
) s
```

Now, every row has its own id. The order criterion may be tweaked a little. Here we have only little chance to change this without any further information. But the algorithm stays the same.

With the ids of each column, we can create a self join to join the parent id by using the `parent` title column. Because a self join is a repetition of the select query, it makes sense to encapsulate it into a second CTE to avoid code replication. The final result is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS 
(  SELECT data[1] as title, 2 as idx, null as parent, data FROM t

   UNION

   SELECT data[idx], idx + 1, title, data
   FROM cte
   WHERE idx <=  cardinality(data)
), numbered AS (
   SELECT 
       *,
       row_number() OVER ()
   FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT
           title,
           parent
       FROM cte
   ) s
)
SELECT 
    n1.row_number as id,
    n1.title,
    n2.row_number as parent_id
FROM numbered n1
LEFT JOIN numbered n2 ON n1.parent = n2.title
```

Comment: Thank you for the very nice example and the implementation, really appreciate it. I did a quick test with a larger dataset of product categories and some reason got some duplicate id's. Any idea why that might happen? Now I also got an another idea, do you know if it would be possible with the sql cte to insert one path/row at once into existing adjacency tree table so it would loop through one path at the time and would insert each node and parent node if doesn't already exist and generates the id and parent_id accordingly?

Comment: I did some more testing and it seems that the query gives a duplicate child node id if the parent node name is same in different path, please see the db<>fiddle. Do you know how to fix this? [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=29904d19033b3ec76865ec5907b43d35)

Comment: Phew, I guess, that makes things much more complex than you mentioned above. As far as I can see, you have not a classical tree. "accessories" has many possible parents, not only one. So, how should the query decide whether or not it is the same element. The duplication comes from the merge on the name which is always a bad idea. You should work with unique ids instead with everything you do.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the example was a little bit incomplete in that regard but didn't realise it before using larger datasets that you can have a node with the same title in the different path. I think if the algorithm would generate two more columns full path for the title and the parent then you could self join the paths? In the final table the id and also the title + parent_id combination are indeed unique constraint so the sibling nodes can’t have a same title but you can have a node with the same title in the different path.

Comment: To avoid the problem with the same title, just use ids. Never work with names. They can change an may break your query. Self joining with paths may work, but sounds not quite performant. But give it a try!

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean just use the ids, what ids you mean? I don’t have any ids as I have an array of names and I am trying to generate the ids. Please have a look this one, what you think [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e1610f4c9da6e259cb5cc6a6a2b4cd4f)? To be honest I really don’t know what I was doing, I just tried to copy your logic and somehow it works. I don’t understand how the recursive part title column works as there is no idx how come it’s able to generate the parent and you also don’t need to use the cast like I am in the title_path?